# SQL Problema con sentencia en una vista

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Tengo el siguiente problema cuento con dos tablas en SQL Server (Tabla A y Tabla B), quiero crear una Vista donde se muestren solo los elementos de la tabla B que no estan en la A. Pensaba que una sentencia parecida a esta ayudaría:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ta.ciudad 
FROM TablaA AS ta
INNER JOIN TablaB AS tb ON ta.Identificacion = tb.Identificacion;
```

Pero no funciona sigue arrojandome resultados de la tabla A

Answer (score 3):

Efectivamente, como bien te indica Sebastián, se trata de un RIGHT JOIN. Únicamente te falta la selección de los elementos de B que no están en A:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TablaB.ciudad
  FROM TablaA RIGHT JOIN TablaB
  USING(Identificacion)
  WHERE TablaA.ciudad IS NULL;
```

Comment: jajaja gracias, se me había pasado eso

Comment: Excelente! Gracias

Comment: La etiqueta de la publicación dice SQL Server y ese RDBMS no maneja JOINs con USING.

Comment: Cierto, no me había fijado en la etiqueta sql-server, disculpad: llevaba la inercia del mysql. El ON que usabais estaba perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que para lo que quieres hacer, tienes que hacer un right join, esto es una consulta que te trae los resultados de la tabla que está a la derecha, que en este caso sería la tablaB.

Ejemplo:

`SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba y dime cómo te va, sino probamos otra cosa.
Saludos

Comment: Buenas Sebastián de esta forma me trae los registros que son iguales, yo necesito los registros de la segunda tabla que NO se encuentran en la primera.

Answer (score 1):

estimados prueba con esta query, debería traer solo los elementos de tablaB que no existen en tabla A.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tablab.ciudad FROM TablaB
LEFT OUTER JOIN TablaA ON TablaB.Identificacion = TablaA.Identificacion 
WHERE TablaA.Identificacion is null;
```

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Es mucho más claro y eficiente usar NOT EXISTS para este tipo de consultas.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ta.ciudad 
FROM TablaA AS ta
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                    FROM TablaB AS tb
                    WHERE ta.Identificacion = tb.Identificacion);
```

Comment: Justo al revés, ¿no? A-B no es B-A. Con respecto a la claridad, totalmente de acuerdo, se entiende mucho mejor. En cuando a la eficiencia, me has hecho dudar, siempre había considerado más eficiente un JOIN. En cuanto tenga un rato hago una prueba de velocidad

Comment: Tienes razón, las tablas están al revés, pero a fin de cuentas es básicamente pseudocódigo. Por otro lado, NOT EXISTS es más eficiente porque usa un `Anti Semi Join`, lo que implica que necesita una menor cantidad de datos para completar la operación. Eso lo explica a detalle Gail Shaw en [su blog](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/).